# Should we remove "Meta Optimize" website suggestion from /help/on-topic page?

Tags: support, status-completed

In the help center *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*, I see a list of SE sites to where certain topics are better suited. But I noticed one of them being a suggestion for a website "Meta Optimize", which I can't find, and it does not appear to be part of SE network, if at all such a website comes back online.

Should we update that help page?

[image: Screenshot from help center]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- I've fixed this.  Thank you for bringing it to our attention.